# How do I pass a stream or writer parameter to a function in Zig?

Tags: zig

I'm trying to pass the output stream to a function but can't get it right. This sample code shows a couple of the things I've tried

```js
// Attempts to pass stream or writer to a function
const std = @import("std");
pub fn main() !void {

  // #1
  try print1(std.io.getStdOut(), "Hello, ");

  // #2
  try print2(std.io.getStdOut().writer(), "world!");

}

// error: 'File' is not marked 'pub'
pub fn print1(file: std.io.File, str: []const u8) !void
{
  try file.writer().print("{s}", .{str});
}

// error: expected type 'type', found 'fn(comptime type, comptime type, comptime anytype) type'
fn print2(writer: std.io.Writer, str: []const u8) !void
{
  try writer.print("{s}", .{str});
}
```

I'm using Zig 0.10.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `std.io.getStdOut()` returns a `File`, but the `File` type is in the `std.fs` namespace. Calling `std.io.getStdOut().writer()` returns a `Writer` from the `std.fs.File` namespace. You could also declare the `writer` parameter with the `anytype` keyword to get type inference at the time of the function call.

Here is a modified version of OP posted code:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const stdout = std.io.getStdOut();
    const writer = stdout.writer();

    // #1
    // Pass `stdout` to a function:
    try print1(stdout, "Hello, ");

    // #2
    // Pass a `Writer` to a function:
    try print2(writer, "world!\n");

    // #3
    // Pass a `Writer` to a function:
    try print3(writer, "Hello, again!\n");
}

fn print1(file: std.fs.File, str: []const u8) !void {
    try file.writer().print("{s}", .{str});
}

// Explicit type annotation for `writer`:
fn print2(writer: std.fs.File.Writer, str: []const u8) !void {
    try writer.print("{s}", .{str});
}

// The type of `writer` is inferred when the function is called:
fn print3(writer: anytype, str: []const u8) !void {
    try writer.print("{s}", .{str});
}
```

And a sample run:

```
$ zig run print_stream.zig 
Hello, world!
Hello, again!
```

Answer (score 4):

[`io.Writer`](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/0.11.0/lib/std/io/writer.zig) is a [generic data structure](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.9.1/#Generic-Data-Structures). I.e. it's a function that returns a type. You cannot use it as a function argument, but you can:

- Use [`anytype`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Function-Parameter-Type-Inference).
- Use an alias, like [`fs.File.Writer`](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/0.11.0/lib/std/fs/file.zig#L1440).
- Use a "proxy" type, like [`fs.File`](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/0.11.0/lib/std/fs/file.zig), on which you'll call [`writer()`](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/0.11.0/lib/std/fs/file.zig#L1442).
- Use full specialization, like [`io.Writer(fs.File, fs.File.WriteError, fs.File.write)`](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/0.11.0/lib/std/fs/file.zig#L1440).

`anytype` is required for functions that must accept arbitrary writers. Otherwise, it might be nicer to use an alias or a "proxy" type.