# How can I use "FixedBufferStream" to create an io.Writer in Zig?

Tags: printing, io, buffer, zig

I am trying to create a writer from an empty buffer so that I can write tests for my function

```
fn writeHello(writer: std.io.Writer) !void {
    try writer.print("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

I used this code from the standard library:

```
var buffer: [128]u8 = undefined;
var fbs = io.fixedBufferStream(&buffer);
const stream = fbs.writer();
```

(with `const std = @import("std");` and `const io = std.io;`).

but `stream` does not have the type `io.Writer` so I cannot pass it to my `writeHello` function.

Comment: Why not make `writer: anytype` and leverage Zig's compile-time ducktyping?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a stream or writer parameter to a function in Zig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74173508/how-do-i-pass-a-stream-or-writer-parameter-to-a-function-in-zig)