# How to accept allvariations of the same generic

Tags: generics, zig

I am learning zig by writing a multi threaded HTTP proxy. As part of this I wrote a function to read from one stream and write it to the other:

```
const std = @import("std");
const http = std.http;

const Source = enum {
    client,
    server,
};

const Reader = union(Source) {
    client: *http.Client.Request.Reader,
    server: *http.Server.Response.Reader,
};

const Writer = union(Source) {
    client: *http.Client.Request.Writer,
    server: *http.Server.Response.Writer,
};

pub fn copy(reader: Reader, writer: Writer, comptime buffer_size: usize) !void {
    var buffer: [buffer_size]u8 = undefined;

    while (true) {
        var nread = switch (reader) {
            .client => try reader.client.*.read(&buffer),
            .server => try reader.server.*.read(&buffer),
        };

        if (nread == 0) {
            break;
        }

        _ = try switch (writer) {
            .client => writer.client.write(buffer[0..nread]),
            .server => writer.server.write(buffer[0..nread]),
        };
    }
}
```

This seems a bit obtuse and is quite clunky to use and extend but what I tried initially doesn't work:

```
const std = @import("std");
const io = std.io;


pub fn copy(reader: *io.Reader, writer: *io.Writer, comptime buffer_size: usize) !void {
    var buffer: [buffer_size]u8 = undefined;

    while (true) {
        var nread = try reader.*.read(&buffer),

        if (nread == 0) {
            break;
        }

        _ = writer.client.write(buffer[0..nread]),
    }
}
```

The compiler complains that `io.Reader` is a function, not a type. I believe if I called `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` with some parameters it would not throw this error, but then the function would only accept the specific variation of the generic rather than the generic itself. I could perhaps require that the generic parameters are passed into the `copy` function but there are a total of 6 parameters that would need to be specified.

There has to be a better way, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a stream or writer parameter to a function in Zig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74173508/how-do-i-pass-a-stream-or-writer-parameter-to-a-function-in-zig)